# C - redefinition because of head inclusion

Tags: c, boolean, redefinition, ansi-c

I program in C with ANCI C and I have a problem with bool definition.
I've created a header bool.h that only contains '''typedef enum { false, true } bool;'''.
The problem is that I have 2 header files, lets call them a.h and b.h that include this bool.h, because they both have prototype of functions that return bool.
And I also have another header file c.h, that includes a.h and b.h, which leads to a compilation error of redefinition of bool.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZHaP.jpg

Comment: Use include/header guards? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard. Or better yet, forget about "ANSI C" and use standard C, `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: I wish I could forget about ANSI C, this is a project I do for a course in the university.
And thank you for the header guards, I haven't heard about it, but I don't think I'm allowed to use it...

Comment: Every C programmer in the world uses header guards for every single header file. Of course you are allowed to use them.

Comment: @Lundin Header guards is the answer this question deserves. Post it as an answer

Comment: Well I’ve asked and I’m not allowed to use inclusion guards...so I need a different solution, but thank you very for helping

Comment: So how did it pan out?

Comment: As `bool` is part of `C99` `stdbool.h`, this is liable to be very confusing to other people (or yourself) looking at this code. I would say, don't fight the standard that you're using is probably reasonable; in this case, it's C90, prefer to use `int` zero for false and non-zero for true.

Answer (score 0):

Lundin is right: header guards is **the** way to do it. Actually, that is probably the only widely accepted way to do it. The constraints of not using header guards is weird indeed, and I can only wonder what's the point of this. Anyways, there *might* be the way to work around it, but it's totally wrong from the practical stand point.

What you can do is this:

main.c:

```
typedef bool {false, true} bool;
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
...
}
```

and then remove `#include "bool.h"` from both a.h and b.h

This *could* do the trick, yet - again - it shouldn't be done that way at all.

Comment: Just realized it was asked over a year ago :-)